# golang program determine if user uses proxy

Tags: http, go, proxy

I want my golang http client to use a proxy only if the user provides the proxy value.

```
// Make HTTP GET/POST request
proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(proxy)
tr := &http.Transport{
      DisableKeepAlives: true,
      Proxy:             http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl),
}
```

The above code always tries to connect through proxy even if the proxy variable is blank.

Comment: You can also look at [func ProxyFromEnvironment](http://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go?h=proxy#L120) as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. Now I am able to make it work. Below is the modified code.

```
tr := &http.Transport{}
tr.DisableKeepAlives = true
if len(proxy) != 0 { // Set the proxy only if the proxy param is specified
    proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(proxy)
    if err == nil {
        tr.Proxy = http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)
    }
 }
```